# 13.10 hangs on waking from suspend except when suspended from console

Tags: 13.10, power-management, suspend, freeze, fglrx

I know waking from suspend is an issue, but this looks like a separate bug.

When I suspend 13.10 on HP Pavillion dv6 (AMD 6770M/fglrx 13.10.10) from x, it suspends normally but freezes when waking. I get a black screen with a frozen cursor.

But when I suspend from console with sudo pm-suspend, it wakes normally, and I can then get back my x with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

If I suspend by closing lid under x, also freezes when waking up. If I suspend by closing lid under console, it wakes up into the x (?) login, then into a clean session.

UPDATE. I checked my syslog, kern.log and pm-suspend.log, they appear to show a standard suspend procedure which is completed normally, then followed by many blank lines (000s), then normal start procedure after hard reset. I may be wrong but looks like kernel panic to me.

Also, if I suspend with dbus ([How can I suspend/hibernate from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1792/how-can-i-suspend-hibernate-from-command-line/131022#131022)) instead of pm-suspend, outcome is same.

Comment: same problem, but my pc hangs 1/5 resumes, console or x doesn't matter

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Seems I have same issue and with help of your testing I found workaround.
Make a script that switch to console before suspend and switch back after resume.

In a terminal run `sudoedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/fglrx-fix` and paste in the following script. Afterwards make it executable by running `sudo chmod u+x /etc/pm/sleep.d/fglrx-fix`

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Script kills autofs when going into standby to eliminate issues with it
case $1 in

suspend)
#suspending to RAM
    chvt 1
    echo "Going to sleep"
    sleep 1
;;
resume)
#resume from suspend 
    echo "try to resume"
    sleep 1
    chvt 7
;;       
esac
```

Comment: The script does the job so I've accepted the answer, thanks. BTW, any particular reason for chmod u+x rather than chmod+x?

Comment: Does the trick for me, thanks! Asus n550jv, Ubuntu 13.10 with nvidia-319-updates drivers here. Fixed blank white screen on wake issue.

Comment: You are a life saver...

Comment: Works on 14.04, Lenovo E520, ATI HD 6630M with fglrx-updates ubuntu package

Comment: Seems to work for most - not for me. Mid 2010 Macbook Pro 6,2 with clean install of 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

Jan's answer worked perfect for me, but the issue would still happen on hibernate. To fix this, I modified a tiny bit of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Script kills autofs when going into standby to eliminate issues with it
case $1 in

suspend|hibernate)  # instead of just "suspend"
#suspending to RAM
    chvt 1
    echo "Going to sleep"
    sleep 1
;;
resume|thaw)  # instead of just "resume"
#resume from suspend 
    echo "try to resume"
    sleep 1
    chvt 7
;;       
esac
```