# Dell latitude E6540 resume crash with catalyst drivers

Tags: drivers, 13.10, ati, dell, suspend

I have a Dell Latitude E6540 with an AMD Radeon HD 8790 and an integrated Intel GPU. I installed AMD Catalyst 3.11 Beta V9.4 drivers in Ubuntu 13.10. It's works fine but suspend/resume doesn't work. It suspends but crashes when resuming.

Is this a known problem? Is there a solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to suspend from a console session to know if it is a duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/369683/13-10-hangs-on-waking-from-suspend-except-when-suspended-from-console

Comment: Haven't tried to suspend using pm-suspend but every other behavior described is the same. Also, unrelated or not, google chrome freezes under catalyst drivers.

Comment: Chrome seems to have a number of (unrelated) issues with Catalyst on Linux such as these: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Fchromium%2Fissues%2Fdetail%3Fid%3D313062&ei=xlGnUv2MKMnlsASkyoCAAg&usg=AFQjCNHmoNbPeSY_boRFA3wutbliyxzYQg&bvm=bv.57799294,d.cWc

Comment: This issue apparently needs filing a bug report, but I still haven't figured out what exactly causes it, and therefore - if it should be filed with AMD or with the Unity development team.

Comment: Maybe agaist Unity first and upstream later?