# Won't wake up after suspend

Tags: suspend

I have freshly installed and updated 13.10
I suspended it for first time yesterday and today it wouldn't start up but just show a blank black page. The monitor goes in power save mode after a while. So nothing happens.

the PC has 12GB ram and 13000 mbytes of swap partition if that matters.

Comment: What video card are you using? Also, does this blank screen only appear when you suspend you PC?

Comment: Probably an autofs bug: http://askubuntu.com/questions/369683/13-10-hangs-on-waking-from-suspend-except-when-suspended-from-console

Answer (score 2):

I am/was having the same issue. Computer has blank screen after resume. It appears that the backlight is just not illuminating because I feel like I can see everything just without light.

HP Compaq Presario F763NR attempting to run with Ubuntu 13.10

I found, however, that I could 'wake' the system by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd>.

First, before this - in order to prevent the computer from crashing when accessing Search your Computer and Resources - I was required to install the System Settings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers > Using NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library from nvidia-304-updates (proprietary).

Solution: create the file ***/etc/pm/sleep.d/99_wake_hack*** to contain:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Action script to activate the screen on resume.
# Without this script, the screen remains blank.
#

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

case "${1}" in
    hibernate|suspend)
            #nothing
            ;;
    resume|thaw)
            chvt 5 && sleep 1 && chvt 7 &
            ;;
esac
```

Essentially, I am switching the foreground virtual terminals. There is a command for this: `chvt 5 && chvt 7`. I require the `sleep 1` and need execute in parallel (`&`) because the fix does not work if the `chvt 7` happens before the wake_hack script (and other resume scripts) are complete.

I look forward to hearing better solutions to this problem.

Answer (score -1):

I pressed <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> (on my laptop: HP Pavilion dv6 3052) for increasing brightness of display and my problem was solved.

Comment: Please confirm that you had the same symptoms as the original poster?

Comment: yes, i hod same problem.