# Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro - Ubuntu 14.xx - X freezes when resuming from suspend

Tags: 14.04, suspend, lenovo, yoga-2

The problem is that my new [Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro (lshw results)](http://pastebin.com/0AdeyZC9) does not resume from suspend very well. I've collected the following data:

1. This happens on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS - both with the original kernel and with the latest 3.16 kernel - and Ubuntu 14.10.
2. The problem only happens when I suspend by closing the lid. It doesn't happen when I suspend from `pm-suspend` utility. I even went as far as running the following:

   ```
   while true; do sudo pm-suspend; sleep 5; done
   ```

   I placed a heavy object on the keyboard, which causes the laptop to immediately resume - and left it for an hour. It never failed to resume correctly. However, when closing the lid, approximately 1 out of 2 closures it will freeze.

   (edited) Another data point, not sure if relevant - when I suspend with `pm-suspend`, the machine won't resume at all when I close the lid and re-open it. When it suspends as a result of closing the lid - opening the lid will resume it... and then the UI freezes. I checked Windows 8.1, and that seems to happen as well - if I command it to sleep, it stays asleep even if I close the lid and re-open it.
3. The computer doesn't freeze, only the window manager. The mouse still moves, but the screen does not update and nothing can be clicked. Switching to a VT works and I'm able to restart the lightdm service and regain control of the GUI:

   ```
   sudo service lightdm restart
   ```

   (at the price of closing all of the graphical applications I had running, so this is **not** a workaround).
4. It's not lightdm's fault - I stopped the `lightdm` service and ran `startx` from the command line. It produces the same symptoms.
5. There's nothing unusual showing up on `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` - I compared it with the output of other people's online posts, and couldn't find a difference. It looks the same, and all important activities succeed.
6. I've modified `/usr/lib/pm-utils/video-quirks/20-video-quirk-pm-lenovo.quirkdb` - I added every combination of quirks I could think of, to no avail.
7. Nothing unusual shows up on `dmesg` - I thought the Intel drive crashed sometime, but it seems to be unrelated because I can't correlate those crashes to a suspend / resume event chain. It seems to be in the Bluetooth driver anyway. [I posted a sample in pastebin](http://pastebin.com/jC6LnR1X).

I'm really out of ideas at this point.

(edited) Well well... just as I was about to turn in, I stumbled across what [seems to be a valid workaround](https://askubuntu.com/questions/369683/13-10-hangs-on-waking-from-suspend-except-when-suspended-from-console). I missed it before because it didn't refer to a version of Ubuntu I was using, but the solution proposed does work for me. Still, I'd like to have a more... elegant... solution, if possible.

Comment: Is the pasted workaround still working for you? I'm trying it in Ubuntu 15.04 on my Lenovo Yoga and it isn't working. Your manual pm-suspend command works great though!

Comment: Can you please post the work around as an answer, if it indeed worked for you?

Comment: @SamuelDeHuszarAllen it was working until a week ago, when my Yoga 2 pro was stolen :(

Comment: @RolandiXor  I guess I don't know how this stackexchange works - when I tried posting an answer referring to the other answer, it converted it to a comment.