# ubuntu 15.10 can not wake up after suspend

Tags: suspend

Having had beautiful Ubuntu about 5 days, I encounter a serious problem when waking from suspension. The machine can enter successfully into suspension mode, but can not wake up once I shake my mouse, which is no problem in Windows. When I try to wake up, the fan starts, the mouse has a red light (reacting), but the screen is black, and the keyboard is not responsive. I then have to force-shut down my computer by holding the power button for about 10 seconds, and then turn it on again, which is very annoying

```
Bios setting: ACPI suspend type is S3, and YES to "run VGABIOS on S3 resume".
```

The graphics card is a GIGABYTE VGA NVIDIA GT610 1GB DDR3 (Passive), using NVIDIA binary driver - version 352.41 from NVIDIA-352 (proprietary, tested). It is very disappointing, without suspension, my computer will waste lots of electricity. What can I do? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
I tried many ways, including [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/369683/13-10-hangs-on-waking-from-suspend-except-when-suspended-from-console) but nothing worked for me. What else can I do?

Comment: Are you on a laptop or desktop?

Comment: Hi, David, it's a desktop. Do you have idea how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Well I'll say that because it is a desktop, rule out both below answer, as neither will be useful on a desktop.

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me.  Do you have an encryption before the login?  If so I have to hit esc or spacebar several times before it responds.  Don't know the cause, but it is open source :) might save electricity.

Comment: Variable Syntax, no, I don't have any encryption before the login.