# Ubuntu 14.04 - sudo pm-hibernate doesn't work

Tags: 14.04, suspend, hibernate

There are a bunch of questions on here about suspend resume error.

The same question appears in: [suspend/resume failure](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279584/suspend-resume-failure) but I don't understand any of the responses.  We are using different laptops (mind is Lenovo) so there may be different types of hardware that are effected.

I tried reading this [tutorial](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-14-04/).  In my case `sudo pm-hibernate` does *not* work in the Terminal, and the configuration steps does not fix this.

I am trying to understand why Hibernate is going wrong, including the discussion [power management/hibernate](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/Hibernate) from the Ubuntu manual.
They suggest there is a problem with `swsusp` but I am not sure how to tamper with that section.

I found `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` in my `/etc/default/grub` file.

Did anyone get this to work?

---

In fact `head /var/log/pm-suspend.log` leads to

```
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change hibernate hibernate:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change hibernate hibernate: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status hibernate hibernate:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status hibernate hibernate: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging hibernate hibernate:
Linux jdm-Lenovo-B570 3.13.0-46-generic #76-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 26 18:52:13 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 16):

I was having the same problem.

```
sudo pm-hibernate
```

...nothing.

```
>~$ dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.UPower" /org/freedesktop/UPower org.freedesktop.UPower.Hibernate
> method return sender=:1.44 -> dest=:1.303 reply_serial=2
```

...nothing.

Looking around, I found a suggestion to check the pm-hibernate log:

```
>~$ head /var/log/pm-suspend.log
> Initial commandline parameters: 
> Wed Apr 29 22:38:06 PDT 2015: Running hooks for hibernate.
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change hibernate
>  hibernate: kernel update inhibits hibernate (/var/run/do-not-
>  hibernate present)
```

Ah! So the system needs to be rebooted because there was a kernel update. It would be great to get some kind of notification of the fact, instead of ...nothing.

BTW, to tell if you need to reboot:

```
>~$ ls -l /var/run/reboot-required
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 32 Apr 29 18:28 /var/run/reboot-required
```

Basically, if that file exists, a reboot is required. 
I can't tell you what will happen if you put the system into hibernation if you need to reboot due to a kernel update, but I was able to hibernate immediately when I did this:

```
>~$ sudo rm /var/run/do-not-hibernate
```

Comment: It's probably worth noting that removing `/var/run/do-not-hibernate` is probably not supported and theoretically dangerous (I guess that sleep image binary compatibility between kernel versions is not guaranteed).

Answer (score 2):

did u try to specify correct swap partition as mentioned in swsusp troubleshooting in [PowerManagement/Hibernate](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/Hibernate)? it fixed pm-hibernate for me. also, i use shutdown mode. I have lenovo z50-70.

My grub file has "quiet splash" too but I simply appended my swap partition beside it.

Comment: How did you do this? I have the same system, same problem.

Comment: its somewhat tricky as behavior is not stable. i tried platform and shutdown mode of kernel method uwsusp. platform mode was not hibernating. shutdown mode worked for me but it could not resume. hence i tried the troubleshooting trick. it worked for me. but still hiccups on the go.

Comment: installing proprietory drivers for nvidia and intel fixed my issue. what about you? is it working yet? i can give some pointers if you need.

Comment: I wish it were that simple, I have hybrid graphics with onboard Intel and AMDGPU, i.e. hell. I can't get AMD to work at all.

Comment: But...Linux is awesome

Answer (score 1):

As you put the link here, swsusp troubleshooting part of [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/Hibernate) worked for me.

### First method

First, you need to check if your swap partition configured correctly. To perform this, initially, run `sudo blkid` and copy the *UUID* of the partition which has the type of *swap* (maybe it's /dev/sda6), I'll call it `<swap uuid>` from now on. Before continuing, you should make a copy as a backup from `/etc/fstab`:

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.back
```

Now open `/etc/fstab` file using such a file editor as `nano` (run it as root). Then, comment every line you see *swap* phrase in it by adding a `#` at the beginning of the line. Here, add this line to the end of file, where `<swap uuid>` is the value you found with `sudo blkid` above:

```
UUID=<swap uuid> none swap sw 0 0
```

Save the file. Maybe the problem with swap partition was fixed.

**Note:** Your swap partition size should be greater than your RAM size; unless you may have problems with hibernating.

### Second method

From the link above, the quoted description, with some changes (see above for using `sudo blkid` to find the value to use for `<swap uuid>` below):

> Problem: The computer goes to hibernate, OK. But after power-on it is loading as if no hibernate state was saved.
>
> In the case of grub2:
>
> 1. You should make a backup. Run:
>
> `sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.back`
>
> 1. Open `/etc/default/grub`;
> 2. Find `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` line. These are the option added to the regular boot menu choices;
> 3. Add the `resume=UUID=<swap uuid>` option to the list like this:
>
> Before:
>
> `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
>
> After (note the quotations):
>
> `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=<swap uuid>"`
>
> **Note:** You might not want to change any options before adding resume (e.g. changing `nosplash` option to `splash`). However, I recommend you to use both `quiet` and `splash` options.
>
> 4. Save the file.
> 5. In the terminal, execute the following command (to actually enable the new configuration settings)
>
> `sudo update-grub2`

Now, try `sudo pm-hibernate` command to hibernate your computer, then try booting again. Your problem may be fixed.

Hope it helps someone!

Comment: The second part, about adding the `resume=UUID=<swap uuid>` part to `/etc/default/grub` worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04. Thanks!